# Returning a JSON float value

Tags: python, json

I am parsing a JSON file with Python. One of they keys I am trying to parse has a `float` value, and I am getting the following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`. Below is the code, JSON, and full traceback.

**Code:**

```
import json

with open('output.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for host in data['ASSET_DATA_REPORT']['HOST_LIST']['HOST']:
    print(host['VULN_INFO_LIST']['VULN_INFO']['CVSS_FINAL'])
```

**JSON:**

```
    {  
   "ASSET_DATA_REPORT":{  
      "HOST_LIST":{  
         "HOST":[  
            {  
               "IP":{  
                  "network_id":"0"
               },
               "TRACKING_METHOD":"EC2",
               "ASSET_TAGS":{  
                  "ASSET_TAG":[  
                     "EC2 Running",
                     "IF - Database - MySQL"
                  ]
               },
               "DNS":"i-xxxxxxx",
               "EC2_INSTANCE_ID":"i-xxxxxx",
               "EC2_INFO":{  
                  "PUBLIC_DNS_NAME":"ec2-xxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com",
                  "IMAGE_ID":"ami-xxxxxx",
                  "VPC_ID":"vpc-xxxxxx",
                  "INSTANCE_STATE":"RUNNING",
                  "PRIVATE_DNS_NAME":"ip-xxxx.ec2.internal",
                  "INSTANCE_TYPE":"m3.xlarge"
               },
               "VULN_INFO_LIST":{  
                  "VULN_INFO":[  
                     {  
                        "CVSS_FINAL":"3.6"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_format.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(host['VULN_INFO_LIST']['VULN_INFO']['CVSS_FINAL'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the value you want to get at being a float. Your structure is a mixture of dictionaries _and_ lists.

Comment: BTW: there are *no JSON floats* in your JSON...

Comment: Yeah, this took me a minute to notice, the "3.6" is a string, because it's a string in your JSON.  Remove the quotes and it'll be parsed as a float by the json module.  There's no good reason to quote numbers in JSON since numbers are supported by the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionary containing the "CVSS_FINAL" key is actually itself in a list. Try:

```
print(host['VULN_INFO_LIST']['VULN_INFO'][0]['CVSS_FINAL'])
```

As an aside, if you want to store this value as type float in Python (rather than string), you could do:

```
value = float(host['VULN_INFO_LIST']['VULN_INFO'][0]['CVSS_FINAL'])
```